# UITableViewAction sometimes freezes table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Sometimes when executing the block of a UITableAction the entire UITableView freezes, it won't respond to taps, or scrolling. However the rest of the page is responsive. The action looks like this

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  __weak ServiceOrderDetailsViewController* weakSelf = self;

  UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Mark as Complete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                {
                                    if (indexPath.section < weakSelf.sections.count && indexPath.row > 0)
                                    {
                                        NSString* key = weakSelf.sections[indexPath.section];

                                        if (indexPath.row - 1 < [weakSelf.datasource[key] count])
                                        {
                                            //Action
                                        }
                                    }

                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                    {
                                        [weakSelf.UITableView_Bins setEditing:NO animated:YES];
                                        [weakSelf.UITableView_Bins beginUpdates];
                                        [weakSelf.UITableView_Bins reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                                        [weakSelf.UITableView_Bins endUpdates];
                                    });

                                }];

button.backgroundColor = [UIColor InTrackGreenColor];

return @[button];
}
```

If I remove the reloadRows this problem does not occur, however then the cell's content is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

So we discovered a work around, that I thought I would share. It's hackish and I would prefer to find a better way, but for the time being it works.

```
[self.UITableView_Bins performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25 inModes:@[NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
```

By delaying for a quarter second, we avoid the freezing issue.